# Bootstrap progress bar -- text remaining

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a stacked bootstrap progress bar:

[image: bootstrap progress bar]

The code to produce this is (in Angular.io, although this is a CSS question):

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
     [ngStyle]="{width:4/16 | percent:'1.0-1'}">
    <span>4</span>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-blue"
     [ngStyle]="{width:10/16 | percent:'1.0-1'}">
    <span>10</span>
</div>
<span>2</span>
</div>
```

I'd like the "2" (i.e. the number remaining) to appear central in the remaining space (the area that's grey on the right of the progress bar). It's currently on the left of where I want it to appear. Is there any way to achieve this using CSS?

Comment: Is `[ngStyle]="{width:0/16` a problem? Will making it `width:2/16` solve it?

Comment: No, in another application that number could be non-zero (it's for something else). I'll remove it from the question for less confusion.

Comment: OK, add a absolute positioned div there and specify float right. And add text 2 within div. That should work

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. Here's the result: http://imgur.com/a/QKnRh Code is: `<div style="position:absolute; float:right;">2</div>`

Comment: All right, see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wz8zfj0y/  Here I have assumed that width on the right will be constant and so added `width:20%`. Is the right content width dynamic?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! That's fixed it. For reference, here's the code when the content width is dynamic: `<div class="third" [ngStyle]="{width:2/8 | percent:'1.0-1'}">2</div>` Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome, all the best. Can I add this as a answer?

Comment: Yes, please do! Thanks again.

Comment: Done. Please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wz8zfj0y/)  Here I have assumed that width on the right will be constant and so added `width:20%`.